Cooling solutions for wide windows
The only window in the main living space of my home where I could put a window A/C unit is 45” wide. There don’t appear to be any window A/C units, or even window fans built for an opening of this size.
Is there a product I’m not aware of for this, and if not, how would I set up something in a way that still keeps bugs and other unwanted things out of the home?

acrylic glass, easy to cut, used for hurricane protection.

You just gotta block off the part of the window that's not filled with A/C unit.  The acrylic suggested above, or some treated plywood, or basically anything hard and waterproof-ish, maybe even pink insulation foam board.
